# Using sed command to add new text in a line

Tags: unix, sed

I have:

```
Format "%x %x %x %x \"%x\" %>x %x \"%{xxx}i\" \"%{xxx}i\""
```

How can I use sed command to make it:

```
Format "%{X-Y-Z}i - %x %x %x %x \"%x\" %>x %x \"%{xxx}i\" \"%{xxx}i\""
```

Basically, I have to add `%{X-Y-Z}i`.

Comment: Currently, this is a just a problem statement, not a question. You should [edit] it and turn it into a question by adding, well, a question, what you've tried, what happened, and what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: quite a simple problem, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/934/getting-started-with-sed#t=20170509053311177556 and ask if you get stuck...

Comment: I dont want to use echo.. can we do it with just sed command ?

Comment: yes, you can directly pass files... for ex: `sed 's/cat/dog/' input.txt `

Comment: Read up on anchoring your regex to start of line. Then replace the empty string at the start of line by what you want inserted. Please understand that the existing comments (including mine) is probably as close as StackOverflow will get to tailor an sed tutorial for you. And if you are just expecting that someone will write the code for you, without providing an [mcve], then you are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/\(^Format\ "\)\(.*$\)/\1%{X-Y-Z}i\ -\ \2/'`

This oneliner is inserting exactly `%{X-Y-Z}i -` between `Format "` and the first occurance of `%`.